# my web page files only half of the mobile screen

Tags: android, iphone, css, html

I have a simple landing page, when i open the page on mobile it fills only half a screen and only when i turn the phone on his side it looks perfect.
how can i make it fills the whole screen of the phone ?
I am looking for the best simple solution - meaning I prefer not to make my page totally responsive, I want it to look exactly like it looks on desktop but to fill the whole mobile screen.
(I tried playing around with the viewport meta tag but with no luck)
I will be grateful for any help I'm kind of lost.

Comment: try to set webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: **Posted as an answer by [Devin Luby](http://stackoverflow.com/u/2735302):** Would you mind providing your code so we can see an example of your mark up?

Comment: Thanks Bharat Jyoti but i really prefer not to turn my project into a java web project, is there some other way to do that?